# How to execute a stored procedure using as a super user?

Tags: sql-server

I connect to MSSQL database with an user that only has rights to his database. Now I have to use that connection to (re)create a linked server.

I would prefer not to make my user a super-user and instead to run the proc that creates the linked server impersonating a sysadmin (I have the username and the password.)

Is that possible?

Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.2269.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition

Comment: Google for _mssql cross database permissions via certificates_. Topics about signing sp and so on. However, such a task does not look like a thing to share to someone who is not a sysadmin. Smells like a terribly bad idea. And I'm not sure if "impersonating sa" will be allowed even after applying certificate's permissions.

Answer (score 1):

The best option here is to create a stored procedure for this task and sign it with a certificate.

1. create a stored procedure for creating linked server
2. create certificate
3. create login from certificate
4. grant appropriate permissions to login
5. sign the procedure with certificate
6. grant execute to low-privileged user